# Insertar fila en una columna con auto_increment MYSQL

Tags: mysql, insert

tengo la siguiente tabla en mysql

El nombre de la tabla es detalle_factura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna id_detalle es auto_increment

Cuando trato de insertar datos dentro de la tabla con el siguiente código, me sale el siguiente error:

```
INSERT INTO `detalle_factura`(`Factura_idFactura`, `Producto_idProducto`, `cant_prod`) VALUES (2,3,4)
```

La tabla detalle_factura está relacionada con factura, subrayé cuál es el fk que me lanza el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría decirme la solución a esto? Gracias.

Comment: Solo no mandes la columna, se autocarga...

Comment: Tienes un error diferente acá, no son el mismo, sugiero editar la publicacion, quitar el primer error y solo consultar el segundo. Pero de todos modos, estás fallando la FK como dice

Comment: El id_factura existe en la otra tabla o no ?

Comment: Sí, es idFactura y está en otra tabla llamada factura

Comment: Podrías agregar esa información ?? por que fallas la FK

Comment: Esta fallando una llave foranea (a lo que los demás llaman FK acronimo de Foreign Key) Podrías mostrar la info de SHOW CREATE TABLE detalle_factura

Comment: Como nota adicional no es bueno estar usando nombres de tablas o campos con mayúsculas en algunos lados y con minúsculas en otros, si migras a Linux eso si importa

Comment: Si da ese error es por que no tienes creada la factura 2 en la table de facturas

Comment: Ehh si, como dice Omar, al momento de yo haber dicho que mostraras esa info, me referia a los datos con el mismo id en ambas tablas XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Este error surge porque en la columna `Factura_idFactura` de la tabla `detalle_factura` se está intentando ingresar un `idFactura` que este no existe dentro de la tabla `factura`.

> Las relaciones de clave externa (FOREIGN KEY) implican una tabla padre que contiene los valores de datos centrales y una tabla secundaria con valores idénticos que apuntan a esta. La cláusula FOREIGN KEY se especifica en la tabla secundaria.
>
> Será rechazada cualquier operación INSERT o UPDATE que intente crear un valor de clave externa (FK) en una tabla secundaria si no hay un valor de clave (PK) candidata coincidente en la tabla padre.
>
> [13.1.17.5 FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)